# How To Create A Five-Star Rating System In Excel using Percentage

Tags: excel-formula, percentage, conditional-formatting

Let me explain briefly below.

we usually apply the five-star ratings to judge the product ratings. So i have followed below steps in order to get the result using percentage.

1. Typed the percentage from 20 to 100 into the columns beside your data as following screenshot shown:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRp1Z.png)[image: Screenshot 1]

2. Then entered this formula **=IF(B$1<=$A3,1,IF(ROUNDUP($A3,0)=B$1,MOD($A3,1),0))** 
   into the cell B3, and drag the fill handle down to the cells to fill this formula. And go on dragging the fill handle to right cells to apply this formula, and we got the following result, see screenshot:

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfyTW.png)[image: Screenshot 2]

3. Select the formula cells, and then click Home > Conditional Formatting > New Rule, see screenshot:

[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AJ4J.png)[image: Screenshot 3]

4. In the popped out New Formatting Rule dialog box, we have done the following operations:

   (1.) Click Format all cells based on their values in the Select a Rule Type list box;

   (2.) In the Format Style drop down list, choose Icon Sets option;

   (3.) Select 3 Stars icon from the Icon Style drop down list;

   (4.) Check the Show Icon Only option;

   (5.) In the rules section, enter 1 and 0.5 separately into the Value text box, and both choose Number from the Type drop down lists.

[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBNOB.png)[image: Screenshot 4]

5. Then click OK button, the five-star ratings have been inserted into the cells, see screenshot:

[5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meClv.png)[image: Screenshot 5]

But if you could see that result, the alignment of the star is wrong. Could anyone please help us with the formula. Please do let us know if you need any clarity.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean with "star rating", and what the expected result should be ?

Comment: which cell is G5?

Comment: I have voted to close the question. It is not clear what you are asking. Your screenshot does not show column letters or row numbers and your formula (which is not working) can't be related to any data. If you want to salvage the question, post a screenshot of the data with identifiable cell references, then post the desired result and then post the logic in plain words that leads from the data in the screenshot to the result you expect.

Comment: Alternatively (speaking to the format of the question) use https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/. Paste your excel data in the top box and choose "Header Type" of "Spreadsheet". Then paste here and format as code. I also have the same question. You say "Star Rating" but you haven't defined that term. What is a "Start Rating" and how does it relate to this data?

Comment: Could you please recheck once with my edited question.

Comment: Would you be able to specify how the alignment is wrong? What do you want it to look like? Are you able to create a mock or sample of what it should look like? Take MS Paint (or other image editor) and create fake results to illustrate your need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
=IF(B$1<=$A3,1,MAX(5*($A3-A$1),))
```

with, for the half-filled icon, `>` rather than `>=` and `0` rather than `0.5`.

[image: Icon set]

(Assumes A1 is blank.)